# count occurrences in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
resp_id visitorID surveyID questionID response answer userID
     43       777      163        736 MS            0      1
     42       777      163        736 Rohit         1      1
     41       777      163        736 Virat         1      1
     40       776      163        736 MS            1      1
     39       776      163        736 Rohit         3      1
     38       776      163        736 Virat         1      1
     37       775      163        736 MS            0      1 
     36       775      163        736 Rohit         1      1 
     35       775      163        736 Virat         2      1
     34       774      163        736 MS            2      1
     33       774      163        736 Rohit         3      1
     32       774      163        736 Virat         1      1
```

I want to count occurrence of each value of "answer" field in table respect to response

I have tried but did not get

```
SELECT count(answer) as answer_cnt
FROM `sg_finished_surveys`
WHERE resopnse = $q GROUP BY `answer`
```

Where `$q` is equal to unique response value.

Comment: no, i want to count occurences of 1,2,3,4,5 in answer column

Comment: You wrote 'resopnse' in your code, instead of 'response'

Comment: use group by visitorID

Comment: Valid values for answer would appear to include 0,1,2, and 3. So where do 4 and 5 come from?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a count and a group by statement to get the number of each type of answer:

```
SELECT 
    count(*) as answer_cnt,
    `answer`
FROM 
    `sg_finished_surveys`
WHERE 
    response = '$q'
GROUP BY 
    `answer`
```

This will count the number of instances of each answer as well as giving you the actual answer.

You also have a typo in your `where` clause (resopnse != response).

You may also want to check out this [Question and Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12475850/1450077) that I posted which covers this type of query and a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

use group by visitorID
ie,

```
 SELECT count(answer) as answer_cnt FROM `sg_finished_surveys`
 WHERE resopnse = $q group by visiterID
```

Answer (score 0):

`$q` need to be in single quote.

```
SELECT count(*) as answer_cnt
FROM `sg_finished_surveys`
WHERE resopnse = '$q' GROUP BY `answer`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(answer)
FROM `sg_finished_surveys`
WHERE respondence = '".$q."'
GROUP BY answer
```